# Android Twitter Cannot access callback

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter, callback, sdk

Im using Twitter 3.0 in my latest app build, and for some reason, I'm getting the error Cannot access callback. "Class file for retrofit2.Callback not found."

I recently upgraded from an older version of the twitter sdk, and this is thje only error I cannot seem to solve. Here is thew method that is throwing the error...

```
@Override
        public void success(final Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
            twitterName = twitterSessionResult.data.getUserName();
            prefs.edit().putString(TWITTER_NAME_PREF, twitterName).apply();
            mTwitterAuthClient.requestEmail(twitterSessionResult.data, new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<String> stringResult) {
                    twitterEmail = stringResult.data;
                    prefs.edit().putString(TWITTER_EMAIL_PREF, twitterEmail).apply();
                    mFragment.twitterInfo(twitterName,
                            twitterEmail);
                    finishLogIn(true, null);
                }
```

That portion "new Callback()" is giving the error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue after moving from compile to implementation